# Размещение элементов в разметке

Tags: java, android, xml

Доброго времени суток. Имеется 8 элементов(кнопок), их нужно разместить в табличном порядке 2 ряда по 4 столбца. В `android:background="@drawable/menu_background"` лежит картинка и под неё надо чтобы точно всё расположилось. Мои манипуляции привели к коду ниже. Все вроде получилось, но, к сожалению, при запуске на другом устройстве с немного другим экраном переместило элементы. Подскажите пожалуйста, какими средствами пользоваться, чтобы отображаемое на разных экранах оставалось одинаковым?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_east"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_india"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_japan"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_canada"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_usa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_samerica"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_mexica"
            android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**UPD**

Получился такой код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/button_menu_africa"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Но на разных устройствах опять же всё смещается...

*240x400*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*1080x1920*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*2560x1600*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажешь backgroun ?

Answer (score 1):

Ну вообще, если нужно разместить 2 ряда с 4-я кнопками, чтобы они были одинаковой ширины, то я бы сделал так (высоту указал для примера) :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Получится примерно так:

[image: Описание изображения]

Comment: Здравствуйте. Оно то вроде так и получается, но стоит закинуть на планшет и всё убежало =( Вот [ссылка](https://www.sendspace.com/file/xmtqew) на background.png и [картинку](https://www.sendspace.com/file/kjaf4f) на кнопку. Остальные кнопки такие же, поэтому для упрощения одну на всех можно.

Comment: @Pollux, ну если делать, как я предложил, то ничего не уедет, потому что у меня размеры кнопок будут меняться, в зависимости от экрана. Главное выбрать правильные отступы по бокам. А если рассматривать вашу размету - то у вас все размеры указаны в статических величинах, поэтому и уезжает всё.

Comment: Не могли бы Вы привести код к данным картинкам? Ширина вроде бы ничего получилось, а теперь по высоте убегает... Путаюсь пока в сложной разметке.

Comment: @Pollux, исправил ответ

Comment: Обновил первый пост **UPD**

Comment: @Pollux, просто сделай бэкграунд ббез текста, а в разметке добавляей кнопки вместе с текстом под ними.

Comment: Так то оно да, но планируется игра по типу найди предмет, и там то тем более нужно чтобы на картинке бэкграунде все точно лежало

Comment: То есть предмет, который надо будет найти, будет изображен на бэкграунде, а пользователю надо будет найти под какой картинкой он?

Comment: Предмет в самом бэкграунде изображен и планировал над предметом ставить прозрачную кнопку

Comment: т.е. положение предмета не меняется и он всегда в одном месте? в чем тогда смысле игры? не лучше иметь возможность расположить предмет куда угодно ?

Comment: Я так понял, Вы намекаете на то, чтобы предмет разместить на кнопке? Допустим, но тогда ведь, если будет сильное смещение предмет может не вписаться в общую картину, например сместится медведь на телевизор